# Facebook SDK for android login

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I tried to make an application which can connect to facebook using the facebook SDK. I've already signed up to facebook developers and made all the necessary things. Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
Facebook fb;
ImageView logButton;
SharedPreferences sp;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String APP_ID = getString(R.string.app_id);
    fb = new Facebook(APP_ID);

    logButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.login);
    logButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) 
{
    if(fb.isSessionValid())
    {
        try 
        {
            fb.logout(getApplicationContext());
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fb.authorize(MainActivity.this, new String[] {"email"}, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "facebook error "+e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() 
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "canceled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{   
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "done1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    fb.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "done2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

I used Toast to know what happens. The application doesnt show any of the messages. It doesnt call onComplete and I dont know why. The dialog is working and when i click on the login button after entering the email and the passowrd, it comes back to the main screen without doing anything. Does anyone knows what is the problem? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me once, I solved it by doing this:
First try to use the code below to print your key hashes, check if the printed key hashes is same as the key hash in you Facebook Developer Dashboard, if they are different, change the one in the dashboard to the printed one.

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "your package", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (android.content.pm.Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK :", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

Comment: I've checked it and its the real hash. This isn't the problem. I had this problem before and it always called "onFacebookError" and I fixed it but now it doesn't call any of them. I used Toast as you can see and it doesn't show any of them. Any other idea?

Comment: are you using the emulator or a handset to debug?